# retrieving value from radio selection and passing it into an endpoint ionic 2+/angular2+

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Just like the title says, how would I go about retrieving an object from a selected radio button value? Once a button is selected that object is then placed into an API endpoint where the user will retrieve more data based on that object.As you see I'm displaying the item description in the view. I would like to retrieve the item id associated with that description.

HTML

```
<ion-content>
<form (ngSubmit)="logForm(form)">
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="value"> 
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-label>{{item.description}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio [value]="value"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-list>
<ion-item>
<ion-label>
  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
  </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
 </form> 
</ion-content>
```

TS

```
export class ItemPage{

items: any;
constructor(){}

getItems(){
this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(item => {
this.items = item
 })
}

logForm(form){
  console.log(form.value)
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` to get the selected item [as the Documentation says](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/), but you have to pass a `name` attribute as well, otherwise Ionic will throw an error. Or, if you want to use a check event, you can use `(ionSelect)` as an attribute of the radio buttons, as the example:

See it in action [here in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-x5fucm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
<h1>Page</h1>

<p>Selected item: {{itemChecked?.id}} {{itemChecked?.description}}</p>
<p>{{log}}</p>

<form (ngSubmit)="logForm(form)">
    <ion-list radio-group name="radio" [(ngModel)]="itemChecked"> 
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" >
        <ion-label>{{item.description}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio (ionSelect)="select(item)" [value]="item"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
        <button ion-button block type="submit">Continue</button>
    </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</form> 
</ion-content>
```

Typescript:

```
items: any;
public itemChecked;
public log;

constructor(){ this.getItems() }

getItems(){
    this.items = [
    { description: 'Item 1', id: 1, },
    { description: 'Item 2', id: 2, },
    { description: 'Item 3', id: 3, },
    { description: 'Item 4', id: 4, },
    { description: 'Item 5', id: 5, },
    { description: 'Item 6', id: 6, },
    ]
}

logForm(form){
    console.log(form.value)
}

select(item) {
    this.log = "SELECTED! " + item.description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the id just pass it `[value]`

```
<ion-radio [value]="item.id"></ion-radio>
```

Comment: Getting an error on submit, cannot get value of undefined

Comment: same here. Did u get any solution